# Which section does objdump disassemble by default

Tags: linux, objdump, bare-metal, disassembly

I am currently building a bare metal executeable, which contains some special sections containing code. However, when I do `objdump -d` I only get the code for the `.text` and `.init.text` sections. The manpage for `objdump` only says that it "only disassembles those sections which are expected to contain instructions" when using the `-d` option. What sections are these, and how does `objdump` tell which sections to decode? I know I can also use the `-D` option to get a full decoding of all sections, but this is usually much more than I need.

Answer (score 6):

`objdump` internally uses [`libbfd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library) to get section information. `objdump` passes a callback to `bfd_map_over_sections()` which calls the callback on each section. When called, `libbfd` passes a `asection *` to the callback, which has a member `type`. If the type contains the flags `SEC_CONTENTS | SEC_CODE` it gets disassembled by `objdump` when the `-d` option is passed.

Getting into `libbfd` is quite harder, I expect that the type detection depends on architecture, but I hope I gave you at least the right pointer. (Probably when having more time I'll dig more into this and extend the answer)..

---

Btw, if you need a script to filter out the sections of interest from `objdump -D` you might use `sed`, like this:

```
# ------------Place section names here ---------------vvv 
objdump -D object.o | sed -rn '/Disassembly of.*\.(comment|text)/{:a;p;n;/Disassembly of/!ba}'
```